# What does a $\mathcal A$-measurable function mean?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I know what a measurable function is but  sometimes I see $\Sigma$-measurable function where $\Sigma$ is some sigma algebra which I don't understand because you need two sigma algebras to define a measurable function.

For example: from Wikipedia

> Let $(X,\mathcal A)$ and $(Y,\mathcal B)$ be measurable spaces. A
> Markov kernel with source $(X,\mathcal A)$ and target $(Y,\mathcal B)$
> is a map $\kappa : \mathcal B \times X  \to [0,1]$ with the following
> properties:
>
> For every (fixed) $B \in \mathcal B$, the map $ x \mapsto \kappa(B,x)$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable
>
> For every (fixed) $ x \in X$, the map $ B \mapsto \kappa(B, x)$ is a
> probability measure on $(Y, \mathcal B)$

Now, when it says that $ x \mapsto \kappa(B,x)$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable, what is the second sigma algebra? is it $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: When the range is contained in $\mathbb R$ (or even $\mathbb R^{k}$) it is understood that we are using the Borel sigma algebra (unless otherwese specified).

Comment: @geetha290krm, does $\mathcal{B}$ here mean the Borel sigma algebra?

Comment: @user3879021 I don't think it does here, but it is indeed confusing.

Comment: $\mathcal B$ is just any sigma algebra on $Y$.

Comment: In many contexts the $\sigma$ field of the range is the Borel $\sigma$ field. However, sometimes the range has a different $\sigma$ field in which case it may need to be explicitly specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x\mapsto \kappa(B,x),\;\;\mathcal{A}$-measurable means that $\kappa$ is a function of $x\in X$. Since it maps to $[0,1]$ then the second $\sigma-$algebra is $\text{Borel}([0,1])$ so we have:

$$k(x|B):(X,\mathcal{A}) \to ([0,1],\text{Borel}([0,1]))$$